# How to use `smart-compile` without confirmation in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I'm using `smart-compile` in Emacs.
It works fine, but if possible I want to omit the confirmation like `Compile command: ruby foo.rb`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use recompile command `M-x recompile`, so Emacs won't ask you for confirmation.